# Pandas Groupby / List to Multiple Rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In this example I have 7 columns total per row. I groupby AccountID and Last Name. Grouping by AccountID and Last Name identifies the same person; the different rows values of Contract, Address, City, and State represents a new location for the AccountID/Last Name.

I would like AccountID/Last Name on one line alongside one or more sets of Contract, Address, City, and State.

Current data looks like this:

| Contract | AccountID | Last Name | First Name | Address | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 622 | 1234 | Pitt | Brad | 466 7th Ave | Park Slope | NY |
| 28974 | 1234 | Pitt | Brad | 1901 Vine Street | Philadelphia | PA |
| 54122 | 4321 | Ford | Henry | 93 Booth Dr | Nutley | NJ |
| 622 | 2345 | Rhodes | Dusty | 1 Public Library Plaze | Stamford | CT |
| 28974 | 2345 | Rhodes | Dusty | 1001 Kings Highway | Cherry Hill | NJ |
| 54122 | 2345 | Rhodes | Dusty | 444 Amsterdamn Ave | Upper West Side | NY |

Would like to display the data like this:

| AccountID | Last Name | First Name | Contract.1 | Address_1 | City_1 | State_1 | Contract_2 | Address_2 | City_2 | State_2 | Contract_3 | Address_3 | City_3 | State_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Pitt | Brad | 622 | 466 7th Ave | Park Slope | NY | 28974.0 | 1901 Vine Street | Philadelphia | PA |  |  |  |  |
| 4321 | Ford | Henry | 54122 | 93 Booth Dr | Nutley | NJ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2345 | Rhodes | Dusty | 622 | 1 Public Library Plaze | Stamford | CT | 28974.0 | 1001 Kings Highway | Cherry Hill | NJ | 54122.0 | 444 Amsterdamn Ave | Upper West Side | NY |

Here is what I've done so far. Steps 5 and on I have been reworking for a week. Any suggestions?

```
# Step 1
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# read from "my clipboard"
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df

#Step 2
df['Contract_State'] = (df['Contract'].astype(str) + '|' + df['Address']  + '|' + df['City']  + '|' + df['State']).str.split()
df['Contract'] = df['Contract'].astype(str)
df['AccountID'] = df['AccountID'].astype(str)

# Step 3 - groupby
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['AccountID', 'Last Name']).Contract_State.apply(list)).reset_index()
df2

# Step 4 - flatten the lists
df2['Contract_State'] = df2['Contract_State'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x).flatten())
df2

# Step 5 - The number of elements in lists each list is always even => /2
num_columns = df2['Contract_State'].apply(len).max()
num_columns 

# Step 6
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(df2['Contract_State']), columns=columns)
df3

# Step 7 - concatenate df2 with contracts, then drop the column "Contract_State"
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], join='inner', axis='columns').drop('Contract_State', axis='columns')
df4
```

Comment: As you can see, there are many ways to reshape your table, but the clear trick is using `groupby` and `cumcount`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, I think you can do it like this:

```
dfg = df.groupby(['AccountID', 'Last Name', df.groupby(['AccountID', 'Last Name']).cumcount() + 1]).first().unstack()
dfg.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in dfg.columns]
df_out = dfg.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str[-1])
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   AccountID Last Name  Contract1 First Name1                Address1       City1 State1  Contract2 First Name2            Address2         City2 State2  Contract3 First Name3            Address3            City3 State3
0       1234      Pitt      622.0        Brad             466 7th Ave  Park Slope     NY    28974.0        Brad    1901 Vine Street  Philadelphia     PA        NaN         NaN                 NaN              NaN    NaN
1       2345    Rhodes      622.0       Dusty  1 Public Library Plaze    Stamford     CT    28974.0       Dusty  1001 Kings Highway   Cherry Hill     NJ    54122.0       Dusty  444 Amsterdamn Ave  Upper West Side     NY
2       4321      Ford    54122.0       Henry             93 Booth Dr      Nutley     NJ        NaN         NaN                 NaN           NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN                 NaN              NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

We can pass a series directly to [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc` first. Use [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate group rows which become the new column suffixes:

```
cols = ['AccountID', 'Last Name', 'First Name']
dfp = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index=cols,
        columns=df.groupby(cols).cumcount() + 1,
        aggfunc='first'
    ).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
)
# Collapse Multi-Index
dfp.columns = dfp.columns.map(lambda t: '_'.join(map(str, t)))
dfp = dfp.reset_index()
```

Or with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) without `groubpy first` since cumcount ensures unique columns:

```
cols = ['AccountID', 'Last Name', 'First Name']
dfw = df.set_index(
    [*cols, df.groupby(cols).cumcount() + 1]
).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
# Collapse Multi-Index
dfw.columns = dfw.columns.map(lambda t: '_'.join(map(str, t)))
dfu = dfw.reset_index()
```

Either option produces:

```
   AccountID Last Name First Name               Address_1      City_1  Contract_1 State_1           Address_2        City_2  Contract_2 State_2           Address_3           City_3  Contract_3 State_3
0       1234      Pitt       Brad             466 7th Ave  Park Slope       622.0      NY    1901 Vine Street  Philadelphia     28974.0      PA                 NaN              NaN         NaN     NaN
1       2345    Rhodes      Dusty  1 Public Library Plaze    Stamford       622.0      CT  1001 Kings Highway   Cherry Hill     28974.0      NJ  444 Amsterdamn Ave  Upper West Side     54122.0      NY
2       4321      Ford      Henry             93 Booth Dr      Nutley     54122.0      NJ                 NaN           NaN         NaN     NaN                 NaN              NaN         NaN     NaN
```

---

The [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/installation.html) module has an abstraction for this operation called [`pivot_wider`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html) which can hide away the collapsing of the MultiIndex and the restoration of the index columns:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
# conda install pyjanitor -c conda-forge
import janitor
import pandas as pd


cols = ['AccountID', 'Last Name', 'First Name']
dfw = (
    df.add_column(
        'group', df.groupby(cols).cumcount() + 1
    ).pivot_wider(
        index=cols,
        names_from='group'
    )
)
```

```
   AccountID Last Name First Name  Contract_1  Contract_2  Contract_3               Address_1           Address_2           Address_3      City_1        City_2           City_3 State_1 State_2 State_3
0       1234      Pitt       Brad       622.0     28974.0         NaN             466 7th Ave    1901 Vine Street                 NaN  Park Slope  Philadelphia              NaN      NY      PA     NaN
1       2345    Rhodes      Dusty       622.0     28974.0     54122.0  1 Public Library Plaze  1001 Kings Highway  444 Amsterdamn Ave    Stamford   Cherry Hill  Upper West Side      CT      NJ      NY
2       4321      Ford      Henry     54122.0         NaN         NaN             93 Booth Dr                 NaN                 NaN      Nutley           NaN              NaN      NJ     NaN     NaN
```

There is also an abstraction to handle the collapsing of the MultiIndex [`janitor.collapse_levels`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.collapse_levels.html) which can be used with the `pandas` operations to create a cleaner look without giving up the flexibility offered by `pivot_table` and `sort_index`:

```
cols = ['AccountID', 'Last Name', 'First Name']
dfp = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index=cols,
        columns=df.groupby(cols).cumcount() + 1,
        aggfunc='first'
    ).sort_index(
        axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False
    ).collapse_levels(sep='_').reset_index()
)
```

`dfp`:

```
   AccountID Last Name First Name               Address_1      City_1  Contract_1 State_1           Address_2        City_2  Contract_2 State_2           Address_3           City_3  Contract_3 State_3
0       1234      Pitt       Brad             466 7th Ave  Park Slope       622.0      NY    1901 Vine Street  Philadelphia     28974.0      PA                 NaN              NaN         NaN     NaN
1       2345    Rhodes      Dusty  1 Public Library Plaze    Stamford       622.0      CT  1001 Kings Highway   Cherry Hill     28974.0      NJ  444 Amsterdamn Ave  Upper West Side     54122.0      NY
2       4321      Ford      Henry             93 Booth Dr      Nutley     54122.0      NJ                 NaN           NaN         NaN     NaN                 NaN              NaN         NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
grp_col = ['AccountID', 'Last Name', 'First Name']
df['num'] = df.groupby(grp_col).cumcount()+1
res = df.set_index([*grp_col, 'num']).unstack('num').sort_index(axis=1, level=1).reset_index()
res.columns = res.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}{x[1]}")
```

**res:**

|  | AccountID | Last Name | First Name | Contract1 | Address1 | City1 | State1 | Contract2 | Address2 | City2 | State2 | Contract3 | Address3 | City3 | State3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | Pitt | Brad | 622.0 | 466 7th Ave | Park Slope | NY | 28974.0 | 1901 Vine Street | Philadelphia | PA | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2345 | Rhodes | Dusty | 622.0 | 1 Public Library Plaze | Stamford | CT | 28974.0 | 1001 Kings Highway | Cherry Hill | NJ | 54122.0 | 444 Amsterdamn Ave | Upper West Side | NY |
| 2 | 4321 | Ford | Henry | 54122.0 | 93 Booth Dr | Nutley | NJ | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 4):

Try with `groupby` and `pivot_table`:

```
df["group"] = df.groupby(["AccountID", "Last Name", "First Name"]).cumcount()+1
output = df.pivot_table(index=["AccountID", "Last Name", "First Name"], 
                        columns='group', 
                        values=['Address', 'City', "State"], 
                        aggfunc='first')
output = output.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
output.columns = [f"{i}_{j}" for i, j in output.columns]
output = output.reset_index()
```