# Reshaping of a data frame in horizontal format with the addition of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data frame `df`

```
ID  Name    Subject     Grade
3   Luke    Chemistry   8
3   Luke    Math        7
1   Marcus  Chemistry   6
1   Marcus  Math        10
1   Marcus  History     9
5   Julia   History     6
```

I reshaped it horizontally. The code I used is

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1.nth(i).add_suffix(i+1)], axis=1)
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

and the result is

```
ID  Name1   Subject1   Grade1  Name2   Subject2  Grade2  Name3   Subject3  Grade3
1   Marcus  Chemistry  6       Marcus  Math      10.0    Marcus  History   9.0
3   Luke    Chemistry  8       Luke    Math      7.0     NaN     NaN       NaN
5   Julia   History    6       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
```

Now I define the list `codes = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]`

I would like to do the same job as before but including all possible elements in codes (if they don't exist in `df` I add a row of `NaN`) and in the same order. In addition I would like to be able to extend the data frame as desired, for example up to 4 (even if there are a maximum of 3 records for a student). In practice, the result I would like to obtain is

```
ID  Name1   Subject1   Grade1  Name2   Subject2  Grade2  Name3   Subject3   Grade3  Subject4  Grade4
4   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN       NaN
3   Luke    Chemistry  8       Luke    Math      7.0     NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN       NaN
1   Marcus  Chemistry  6       Marcus  Math      10.0    Marcus  History    9.0     NaN       NaN
5   Julia   History    6       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN       NaN
2   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN       NaN
```

What is the best way to modify the previous code to get this latest version of the data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the `codes` list to add the missing rows and establish desired ordering.

Modification of OP's code:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1.nth(i).add_suffix(i + 1)], axis=1)

# reindex before reset_index
codes = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
# Describe New Number of columns
to_add = 1
# Needed to calculate new columns
cols = df.columns.difference(df2.index.names)
cur_num = df2.columns.size // cols.size
# Reindex both index and columns to reorder codes and add need columns
df2 = df2.reindex(
    index=codes,
    columns=df2.columns.union(
        [f'{n}{i}'
         for n in cols
         for i in range(cur_num + 1, cur_num + to_add + 1)],
        sort=False
    )
).reset_index()
```

`df2`:

| ID | Name1 | Subject1 | Grade1 | Name2 | Subject2 | Grade2 | Name3 | Subject3 | Grade3 | Grade4 | Name4 | Subject4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | Luke | Chemistry | 8 | Luke | Math | 7 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | Marcus | Chemistry | 6 | Marcus | Math | 10 | Marcus | History | 9 | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | Julia | History | 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

---

We can also create the DataFrame slightly differently without needing to iterate over every row in the DataFrame (based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69089594/15497888) here) then do the reindexing:

```
col = 'ID'
# Pivot to wide form
df2 = df.pivot_table(
    index=col,
    columns=df.groupby(col).cumcount() + 1,
    aggfunc='first'
).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)

# Collapse Multi-Index
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda t: ''.join(map(str, t)))

# Handle the Reindexing of ID column
codes = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
# reindex ID then reset index
df2 = df2.reindex(codes).reset_index()
```

`df2`:

| ID | Grade1 | Name1 | Subject1 | Grade2 | Name2 | Subject2 | Grade3 | Name3 | Subject3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | 8 | Luke | Chemistry | 7 | Luke | Math | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 6 | Marcus | Chemistry | 10 | Marcus | Math | 9 | Marcus | History |
| 5 | 6 | Julia | History | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

---

To handle adding additional columns `reindex` the columns as well as the index:

```
col = 'ID'
# Pivot to wide form
df2 = df.pivot_table(
    index=col,
    columns=df.groupby(col).cumcount() + 1,
    aggfunc='first'
).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)

# Handle the Reindexing of index and columns
codes = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
col_nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # range(1, 4 + 1)
df2 = df2.reindex(
    index=codes,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        df2.columns.levels[0],
        col_nums
    ])
).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
# Collapse Multi-Index
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda t: ''.join(map(str, t)))
# The Reset Index
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

Alternatively, only set the number of new columns to add:

```
# Describe only number of columns to add
to_add = 1  # add 1 additional column
df2 = df2.reindex(
    index=codes,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        df2.columns.levels[0],
        range(1, df2.columns.levels[1].size + 1 + to_add)
    ])
).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
```

`df2`:

| ID | Grade1 | Name1 | Subject1 | Grade2 | Name2 | Subject2 | Grade3 | Name3 | Subject3 | Grade4 | Name4 | Subject4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | 8 | Luke | Chemistry | 7 | Luke | Math | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 6 | Marcus | Chemistry | 10 | Marcus | Math | 9 | Marcus | History | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | 6 | Julia | History | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5],
    'Name': ['Luke', 'Luke', 'Marcus', 'Marcus', 'Marcus', 'Julia'],
    'Subject': ['Chemistry', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Math', 'History', 'History'],
    'Grade': [8, 7, 6, 10, 9, 6]
})
```

Comment: Your solution is partially correct. Please note that one should be able to insert any number of extra columns (columns of  `NaN `). For example, in the question I have inserted 4 columns ( `Subject4 ` and  `Grade4 `) even if the maximum of each student's exams is a maximum of 3.

Comment: Simple enough to also reindex the columns. Either building the new values in the first block, or reindexing a specific level as in the second section. Please review the edits.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but I am suspecting that you it would be much easier to continue your analysis by just pivoting the original dataframe:

```
res = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Subject', values='Grade')

Subject  Chemistry  History  Math
Name                             
Julia          NaN        6   NaN
Luke             8      NaN     7
Marcus           6        9    10
```

In your example the subject numbering seems arbitrary, because it changes if the order of the grades changes. I would think that would lead to confusion down the road.

Maybe if you let us know what your next step here would be, someone could come up with an elegant way to get there.

Comment: In fact, I have only given one example of what I want to do. In the real case I am working on, each id (and therefore each row) has 30 fields, and the format that is required for the data frame is the one I indicated in the final part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to add `NaN` values for all the ID's that are not yet in `df['ID']`, right?

In that case, just add the following code to your example:

```py
add_rows = [i for i in range(1, df['ID'].max()) if i not in df['ID'].unique()]
df2 = df2.append([{'ID': r} for r in add_rows])

print(df2)
```

This should give you:

```
   ID   Name1   Subject1  Grade1   Name2 Subject2  Grade2   Name3 Subject3  Grade3
0   1  Marcus  Chemistry       6  Marcus     Math      10  Marcus  History       9
1   3    Luke  Chemistry       8    Luke     Math       7     NaN      NaN     NaN
2   5   Julia    History       6     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
3   2     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
4   4     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
```

I do not see how you want the dataframe sorted.