# Transpose rows of a Multi-index df into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, multi-index

I have a df that looks like this:

```
                       pid    time    
id           vid      

id1         vis_id1    pid1    t_0      
            vis_id1    pid2    t_1       

id2         vis_id2    pid1    t_3      
            vis_id2    pid2    t_4      
            vis_id2    pid3    t_5      
            vis_id2    pid4    t_6
```

I am looking to transpose the rows of the df for the `pid` and `time` for some `n` number of rows for each `i`

Before:

```
                       pid    time    
id           vid      

id1         vis_id1    pid1    t_0      
            vis_id1    pid2    t_1       

id2         vis_id2    pid2    t_3      
            vis_id2    pid2    t_4      
            vis_id2    pid3    t_5      
            vis_id2    pid4    t_6
```

After:

```
                     step1   step2     step3  step4      
id           vid      

id1         vis_id1    pid1     pid2     NA     NA         
                     
id2         vis_id2    pid1     pid2    pid3   pid4
```

So the original `pid` becomes step 1 (I can just rename the column before I  transpose) and then the previous `pids` are transposed such that they maintain their order (up->down) to (left->right). It would be helpful to remove the columns with time as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can enumerate groups using [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) based on level=0, add as an additional level of the index ([`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` to add to existing MultiIndex), then `unstack` into columns:

```
new_df = df.set_index(
    df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1, append=True
).unstack()
```

`new_df`:

```
              pid                   time               
                1     2     3     4    1    2    3    4
id  vid                                                
id1 vis_id1  pid1  pid2   NaN   NaN  t_0  t_1  NaN  NaN
id2 vis_id2  pid1  pid2  pid3  pid4  t_3  t_4  t_5  t_6
```

---

To match shown output select only the columns desired, and flatten MultiIndex:

```
new_df = df[['pid']].set_index(
    df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1, append=True
).unstack()
new_df.columns = [f'step{i}' for i in new_df.columns.get_level_values(1)]
```

`new_df`:

```
            step1 step2 step3 step4
id  vid                            
id1 vis_id1  pid1  pid2   NaN   NaN
id2 vis_id2  pid1  pid2  pid3  pid4
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2', 'id2', 'id2'],
    'vid': ['vis_id1', 'vis_id1', 'vis_id2', 'vis_id2', 'vis_id2', 'vis_id2'],
    'pid': ['pid1', 'pid2', 'pid1', 'pid2', 'pid3', 'pid4'],
    'time': ['t_0', 't_1', 't_3', 't_4', 't_5', 't_6']
}).set_index(['id', 'vid'])
```

Related reading [Pandas Groupby / List to Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089182/pandas-groupby-list-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: Hi Henry, I 'm getting the following error:

Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow. I just saw you updated the question let me try that.

Edit: the error is still there