# Split a large pandas df into n equal parts and store them in a list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a very large df which I am trying to transpose (rows->columns) but I get the following error: 'Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow'

Instead I am trying to split my df into `n` number of equal sized parts so I can transpose them and then concatenate them.

My df is a multi-index df with two levels so when I split the df I would like it to split through the first index (level = 0) index. I have tried `np.array_split()` but I am unsure whether it splits by row length or index length.

Comment: Did you try to transpose the values and next recreate the dataframe: `pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, index=df.columns, columns=df.index)`?

Comment: it is a bit of a complicated transposition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259069/transpose-rows-of-a-multi-index-df-into-columns/69259114#69259114   , however I will see what I can do from that angle..

Comment: Do you mean the previous answer does not work for your case?

Comment: Yea, it gives me the error I mentioned here. However, I don't think transposing the values before hand would work. Im better off just iterating through df chunks and combining towards the end so I can use the previous' answers code.